# Is there a cleaner or more clever way to output the contents of an array besides a simple for loop?

Tags: javascript

In the example below I output the contents of an `array` named creatures to a DIV.  I used a simple `for` loop to add each index and value to a variable named tempCreatures.  Then I replaced the `textContent` inside the DIV with tempCreatures.  It works and its simple but I wonder if there is a more clever way to do this.  I experimented with `forEach` and other ideas but couldn't produce anything that worked.  **Does Javascript have a better/cleaner/cooler/more efficient way to do something like this?**

```js
'use strict';

var creatures = ['zombie', 'skeleton', 'orc', 'goblin']

function readCreatures() {

  let i, tempCreatures;
  
  tempCreatures = '';
  
  for(i = 0; i < creatures.length; i++) {
    tempCreatures += i +': ' +creatures[i] +', ';
   }
   
   document.querySelector('.output').textContent = tempCreatures;
 }
 
 readCreatures();
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: This is highly opinionated. You can use `map`, `join` and other functions, but who deems what to be cleaner/cooler/more efficient?

Comment: Totally wrong.  I've learned so much from the answers to this question.

Comment: Of course there are many solutions, and these are exactly the type of questions where people learn the most. Some of these "on hold" decisions actually hurts stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the last comma, (in your example you don't) you can use forEach. The last comma can be removed with slice() or use map/join as suggested above.

```js
'use strict';
var creatures = ['zombie', 'skeleton', 'orc', 'goblin'];
    
function readCreatures() {
  let tempCreatures = '';

  creatures.forEach((c,i) => tempCreatures += i + ': ' + c + ', ');
       
  document.querySelector('.output').textContent = tempCreatures;
}
     
readCreatures();
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the data to a new array setting each new value similar to what you are doing then `join()` the new array to return a string

```js
'use strict';

var creatures = ['zombie', 'skeleton', 'orc', 'goblin']

function readCreatures() {

  let text = creatures.map((v,i)=> i + ': ' + v).join(', ')
   
   document.querySelector('.output').textContent = text;
 }
 
 readCreatures();
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can use `join`, but that won't work in this situation due to the prefixed `i + ":"`.

You can use `reduce` (with an arrow function for brevity) like:

```
var tempCreatures = creatures.reduce((s, e, i) => s + i + ": " + e + ", ", "");
```

Or `map` then `join` (again using an arrow function) like:

```
var tempCreatures = creatures.map((e, i) => i + ": " + e).join(", ");
```

**Note:** The `reduce` approach will cause a trailing `", "` at the end of `tempCreatures` as does the `for` loop. Where as in the `map` and `join` combo there is no trailing `", "`.

Read more about [**`join`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [**`map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**Arrow Functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

Using map or reduce are likely the best choices. But here is a solution that isn't better than a loop but it was fun to think of the problem in this way. Use recursion (pretty redundant for a loop but still was fun)

```
 var creatures = ['zombie', 'skeleton', 'orc', 'goblin']

 const recursiveStringBuilder = (temp, arr, length) => {
   temp = `${temp}  ${length} : ${arr[length]}, `;
   return arr.length -1 === length ? temp : recursiveStringBuilder(temp, arr, length + 1);
 }

 function readCreatures() {
    const tempCreatures = recursiveStringBuilder('', creatures, 0);
    document.querySelector('.output').textContent = tempCreatures;
 }

 readCreatures();

 <div class="output"></div>
```